# Access child scope corresponding to a model variable

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of items and I've rendered them in a template via `ng-repeat`. Each of them is controlled by an `itemController` which exposes some behavior for item (e.g. grabing focus). Here is the HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="mainController">
  <button ng-click="addItem()">add</button>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-controller="itemController">
      <div ng-if="item.isEditing">
        <input ng-model="item.name"/>
        <button ng-click="item.isEditing=false">done</button>
      </div>
      <span ng-if="!item.isEditing">{{item.name}}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </body>
```

In the `mainController`, I have a function for adding a new item to *items*. Here is the code for mainController:

```
app.controller('mainController', function($scope){
  $scope.items = [
    {
      name: "alireza"
    },
    {
      name: "ali"
    }
  ];
  $scope.addItem = function(){
    $scope.items.push({isEditing: true});
  }
});
```

Whenever I add an item to `items` array, a corresponding `li` element is added into the **view** which is **controlled** by an instance of `itemController`, and the corresponding **model** is the new item I've just added (or maybe the `scope` of the `itemController`, which **contains** item).

## Problem:

When I add some item to `items`, I only have access to `item` and not the scope of the recently created item. So I can't run some function (like grabFocus) on the scope of new item.
Is it something semantically wrong in my design? What is the canonical approach for this problem?

## Plunker link

[Here is the plunker link with related comments](http://plnkr.co/edit/MxRBOenphI1xZSaEF1Br?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$broadcast` from the parent scope, along with `$on` from the child scope, to notify the child scopes of the newly added item. And by passing (as an argument) the `$id` of the child scope that corresponds to the newly added item, each child catching the event can know whether or not it's the one that needs to have `grabFocus()` called.

Here's a [fork of your Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zTiUkPGkx4GKxsdggz8N?p=preview) that uses that approach. I wasn't sure what you were trying to accomplish with `$element.find(":text").focus();` in your original Plunker, so I tweaked it to toggle a `$scope` property that in turn controlled a style in the view. The newly added item will be red (by calling its own `grabFocus` function to toggle the flag to `true`), and the others will be black (by calling their own `loseFocus` function to toggle the flag to `false`).

Modified HTML (just the repeated `li`):

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-controller="itemController">
  <div ng-if="item.isEditing">
    <input ng-model="item.name"/>
    <button ng-click="item.isEditing=false;handleItemAdded($index);">done</button>
  </div>
  <span ng-if="!item.isEditing" ng-style="{ color: isFocused ? 'red' : 'black' }">{{item.name}}</span>
</li>
```

Full JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module("app",[]);
app.controller('mainController', function($rootScope, $scope){
  $scope.items = [ { name: "alireza" }, { name: "ali" } ];
  $scope.addItem = function(){
    $scope.items.push({isEditing: true});
  };
  $scope.handleItemAdded = function (index) {
    // $rootScope.$broadcast('item-added', { index: index });
    for(var cs = $scope.$$childHead; cs; cs = cs.$$nextSibling) {
      if (cs.$index === index) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('item-added', { id: cs.$id });
        break;
      }
    }
  };
});
app.controller('itemController', function($scope, $element){
  $scope.$on('item-added', function (event, args) {
    if ($scope.$id === args.id + 1) {
      $scope.grabFocus();
    } else {
      $scope.loseFocus();
    }
  });
  $scope.grabFocus = function() { 
    $scope.isFocused = true;
  };
  $scope.loseFocus = function() { 
    $scope.isFocused = false;
  };
});
```

Comment: ...or, if you'd like to avoid `$$`-prefixed properties which may become deprecated, here's an updated Plunker with a cleaner approach which avoids those: http://plnkr.co/edit/DjJBADTuAJ5GBSxXEqYg?p=preview

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I already did something like this but I was wondering whether it's the best practice or not. I think it doesn't seem a reasonable pattern to broadcast to everyone. I was wondering whether the whole thing I'm trying to do is wrong and against MVC, and this **broadcast** solution is only a workaround to do this bad thing! And if so, then what's the canonical solution to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

I changed your approach a little bit by creating an unique id for every input, based on its index number. See code below, hope it helps.

```js
// Code goes here


var app = angular.module("app",[]);
app.controller('mainController', function($scope,$timeout){
  $scope.items = [
    {
      name: "alireza"
    },
    {
      name: "ali"
    }
  ];
  $scope.addItem = function(){
    $scope.items.push({isEditing: true});
    $timeout(function(){
      document.getElementById("newItem"+($scope.items.length-1)).focus();
    },0)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.0" data-semver="1.3.0" src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/angular.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="mainController">
  <button ng-click="addItem()">add</button>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
      <div ng-if="item.isEditing">
        <input ng-model="item.name" id="newItem{{$index}}"/>
        <button ng-click="item.isEditing=false">done</button>
      </div>
      <span ng-if="!item.isEditing">{{item.name}}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you,but I think this is a workaround, not a clean solution for these situations. Assume that there was a more complicated work instead of grabbing focus. I think it's `item`s concern and should not be handled in outer controller.